# How do I display images in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I am having trouble displaying an image in php.  In the first file I have an input that gets the image. `<input type="file" name="imageOrVideo" accept="video/*,image/*" multiple>`.  In a second php file I want to get the image and display it.  I get the file using `$imageOrVideo = $_POST['imageOrVideo'];`  If I echo $imageOrVideo all I get is a string.  I tried using echo img `echo "<img src=Image/".$imageOrVideo."/>";` and `echo  "<img src=".$imageOrVideo."/>";`  But neither worked.  I read that you can only echo strings so maybe I should not use echo but some other method to display an image. Here is the full code so as to see where the problem might be.  Thanks for any help.
This is the first file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Recipe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/createRecipe.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
    <a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Sign Out</a>
    <a href="">My Recipes</a>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
</div>

<form action="includes/createRecipe.inc.php" method="post">
<div class="leftSide">

<input type="file" name="imageOrVideo" accept="video/*,image/*" multiple><br><br>
<!--
 <input type="file" name="imageOrVideo" accept="image/*" ><br><br>
 --> 


<div class="prepTimeCookTime">
<label>Prep Time</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="prepTime" class="prepTime"> </textarea><br>

<label>Cook Time</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="cookTime" class="cookTime"> </textarea><br>
</div>

<div class="readyTimeNumberOfServings">
<label></label>Ready Time<br><br>
<textarea type="" name="readyTime" class="readyTime"> </textarea><br>

<label>Number of Servings</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="numberOfServings" class="numberOfServings"> </textarea><br>
</div>
</div>

<div class="rightSide">
<label>Recipe Title</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="recipeTitle" class="recipeTitle"> </textarea><br>

<label>Description</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="description" class="description"> </textarea><br>

<label>Ingrediants</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="ingredients" class="ingredients" placeholder="Put each ingrediant on its own line."></textarea><br>

<label>Directions</label><br><br>
<textarea type="" name="directions" class="directions" placeholder="Put each step on its own line."></textarea><br>

<button type="submit" name="recipe-submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the second file.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['recipe-submit'])){

        require 'dbh.inc.php';
        session_start();
        

        $imageOrVideo = $_POST['imageOrVideo'];
        $uidUsers = $_SESSION['userUid'];
        $prepTime = $_POST['prepTime'];
        $cookTime = $_POST['cookTime'];
        $readyTime = $_POST['readyTime'];
        $numberOfServings = $_POST['numberOfServings'];
        $recipeTitle = $_POST['recipeTitle'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
        $directions = $_POST['directions'];
        
        //echo "<img src='" . $_POST['imageOrVideo'] . "' alt='img'>";
        //echo "<img src='/images/test/" . $_POST['imageOrVideo'] . "' alt='img'>";
        //print $imageOrVideo;
        //echo  "<img src=".$imageOrVideo."/>";
        //echo "<img src=Image/".$imageOrVideo."/>";


        

/*
        $sql = "INSERT INTO recipes (videoOrImages, uidUsers, prepTime, cookTime, readyTime, numberOfServings, recipeTitle, description, ingredients, directions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                        header("Location: ../createRecipe.php?error=sqlError");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else{
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "bsssssssss", $imageOrVideo, $uidUsers, $prepTime, $cookTime, $readyTime, $numberOfServings, $recipeTitle, $description, $ingredients, $directions);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
                        exit();
                    }   
                
                    

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            
            */
    }

    else{
        header("Location: ../createRecipe.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Post more code please with details of first problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Each question should just be about one single problem. You  can update your question using the edit link to include one question and create a new question for any other problems you have. Please also include all the relevant code you are using for the first problem in a [**minimal,reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see what you are doing and where the problem might be.

Comment: your not actually managing the file upload. You need to upload the file then you can insert the file name in your DB. Quick google search for 'php file upload' will give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comment your not actually managing the uploaded file. try something like this :

```
    $uidUsers = $_SESSION['userUid'];
    $prepTime = $_POST['prepTime'];
    $cookTime = $_POST['cookTime'];
    $readyTime = $_POST['readyTime'];
    $numberOfServings = $_POST['numberOfServings'];
    $recipeTitle = $_POST['recipeTitle'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
    $directions = $_POST['directions'];
    $imageOrVideo = $_POST['imageOrVideo'];

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/'; //or wherever you want to upload the file
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $imageuploaded = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

   // then check to see if its actually an image

   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
   if($check !== false) {
   echo "File is an image";
   $imageuploaded = 1;
   } else {
   echo "File is not an image.";
   $imageuploaded = 0;
   }

   // you can check to see if the file already exists
  
   if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
   $imageuploaded = 0;
   }

   // then process the file

  if ($imageuploaded == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

  // if everything is ok, try to upload file

  } else {

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
```

if you wanted to make sure its a specific file type you can try something like this :

```
  // Allow certain file formats

  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
  && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }
```

i haven't tested the code but it should work or at least set you off on the right path